# how to associate a file type "sh3d" with an application Sweet Home 3D?

Tags: unity, default-programs, file-type

I installed Sweet Home 3D from Ubuntu Software Center. Application is shown in a list of installed aplication and it could be run from launcher. Default file type of the program is ".sh3d". Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04 and 15.10 open this type of file with Archive  Manager. However, in dialog "Open with", application "Sweet Home 3D" is not shown. How to associate this file type (sh3d) with an application Sweet Home 3D (command for starting the application is "sweethome3d")?

Here is "Open with" dialog. Button Add can only add Other application in a list to Default application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the "open with" dialog, there should be an option to "use a custom command". In there, enter the name of the command for starting the application (i.e. "sweethome3d").

Comment: but there is no such think. Custom commands can't be entered.

Comment: I think that part of the dialog is collapsed by default. Maybe you could post a screenshot of what you get when you open the "open with" dialog?

Comment: I uploaded the image of dialog...

Comment: No you're in the wrong dialog. You need to right-click on a ".sh3d" file and choose "open with other application" (or something like that; I'm at a Windows machine right now). That's the dialog where you can enter a custom command.

Comment: I tried this approach as well but it does not allow me to enter custom command. There is only "Find online application" (Ubuntu 14.04), which does not help me at all.